# Android starts Components from the middle of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a screen contains just two components
1-textView
2-button
the textView starts from the top left of the screen but i want it to starts from the middle of the screen not from the top

i read that cravity option will center my textView

this is the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFinishTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time Is End"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFinishTimeBackToMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You want TextView on center of screen, where you want button to be???Can you use relativelayout??

Comment: @iNan i want the textView to be and the middle of the screen and at the center, and the button down of the textView , and i don't know relativelyaout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do it using `android:gravity="center"`, You can also do it using RelativeLayout.
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFinishTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Time Is End"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFinishTimeBackToMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvFinishTime"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this makes the button apove the textView ( i mean the textView doesn't appear),

Comment: i want to textView to be at the middel of the screen , i mean like padding in css

Comment: But the above code makes TextView on the center of screen, wait i will check

Comment: Well i have uploaded image, you want it to look like as it is in Image right??

Comment: Are you modifying view using java code?? If not above code should work

Comment: no i didn't , but please look at this image , that is what i see http://www.mediafire.com/?g628v1b9dopl0t5

Comment: As Nouran said android:gravity="center" in your parent layout :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:gravity="center"` in your parent LinearLayout. I tried it and it worked.